# How would you make html/css of transparent circle inside filled square div?

Tags: html, css

There is a task to make html/css of pretty unusual designed block: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8esOY.png)

Any ideas?

Here is my code:
but the shadow image isn't displayed in FF :(

```
<section class="service-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item">
                        <object data="" type="">
                        <svg viewbox="-7 -1 24 19" style="background-image: url('/img/ic_advantages-1_calc.png')">
                            <path d="M-10 -1 H30 V18 H-10z M 5 8 m -5, 0 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0z"/>
                            <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="/img/circle_shadow.png" ></image>
                        </svg>
                        </object>

                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="title"><a href="">Some link</a></div>
                            <div class="price">from 3 000 <span class="rub">₽</span>per year</div>
                            <div class="inluded"><a href="">Go?</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: P.S. There is a shadow inside. And moreover the whole block is responsible!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it...with one div.

**Radial gradient and drop-shadow.**

```css
body {
  background: #c0ffee;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center 75px, transparent, transparent 50px, red 50px);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px -4px 4px black);
-     filter: drop-shadow(0px -4px 4px black);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*OR*

**Pseudo-element with giant box-shadow..and drop-shadow**

```css
body {
  background-color: #c0ffee;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px -4px 4px black);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px -4px 4px black);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50px;
  top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: There is a problem with rounded corners of parent div. I mean is there any way to have rounded parent element and included children with position relative?

Comment: I would suggest you ask a **new question** rather than add additional comments to this one.

Answer (score 0):

How to round corners of children elements with position: relative. Moreover if there are 2 such blocks with the shadow it overlaps like this: https://yadi.sk/i/1lXwqKTatpvue